# How to change the color of the selection Borders

Tags: windows-phone-8

We're developing a beautiful WP8 app, and our designer found that when a text is selected, the text selection borders are painted in the Theme color (Purple in the screenshot-crop).

[image]

Can we change it to conform to our color scheme?

Comment: I've never seen anything to affect the colour of the selection borders.  Colours are changed in styles, and you don't have a style for "selection borders"...  Are you changing the style for selected text in this text box?

Comment: @PeterRitchie - Yes. That's why the selection colour is cyan-like, as the textbox border and the "Drift" header, and not purple like the boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly,

I believe it's most likely out of our reach to change as developers.

Comment: +1 for answering, but I refuse to mark it as answer. There must be some hack to control it...